# Source and translation of the shloka

Tags: scripture, shloka

> सौराष्ट्रावन्त्याभीराश्च शूरा अर्बुदमालवाः । व्रात्या द्विजा भविष्यन्ति शूद्रप्राया जनाधिपाः (saurāṣṭrāvantyābhīrāśca śūrā arbudamālavāḥ | vrātyā dvijā bhaviṣyanti śūdraprāyā janādhipāḥ)

I got that shloka on a site. I want to know about it's source and translation. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is that wedsite

Comment: I did a Google search and got to [this](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/vratya) page. It is giving the location as Bhagavata Purana 12.1.38 but the verse no. is slightly wrong as the answer shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from the bhAgavata purANa, [12.1.36 or 38](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/1/36/), which discusses the lines of kings in kaliyuga. The verse is numbered as 36 or 38 in different versions.

> At that time the brāhmaṇas of such provinces as Śaurāṣṭra, Avantī, Ābhīra, Śūra, Arbuda and Mālava will forget all their regulative principles, and the members of the royal order in these places will become no better than śūdras.

[Alternative translation- Motilal](https://archive.org/details/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/page/n2153/mode/2up)

> The twice-born castes of Śaurāṣṭra, Avantī, Ābhīra, Śūra, Arbuda and Mālava will become fallen (due to the lapse or non-performance of samskaras, such as the investiture of the sacred thread) and the rulers of these people will be mostly of śūdra castes.

[Gita Press translation](https://archive.org/details/bhagavatapuranagitapress_201907/page/n1535/mode/2up)

> (As Kaliyuga advances) the Brahmanas of Saurastra, Avanti, the Abhira territory and the principalities of Sura, Arbuda and Malawa will become Vratyas or fallen men (because of their giving up the Samskaras or purificatory rites, especially the ceremony of investiture with the sacred thread), and the rulers will be mostly of the Sudra class.

Comment: Is it 38 or 36?

Comment: Different editions number it in different ways. Motilal and Gita Press had it as 38, but the BBT translation had it as 36. I don't know if this is because source manuscripts were missing some text, or different methods of numbering verses in the same text. The site that you linked to in the comment at the top of this page also has it as 36.

Comment: The Vedabase website, which you linked at the start of the answer, shows it as 36 but you have mentioned it as 38. That's why I have asked. I have posted a link of a site under the question which too mentions the location to be 12.1.38.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer upvoted